# Copy-Item gets IOException when copying to the destination

Tags: powershell

I'm getting an IOException when `Copy-Item` copies files to the destination even though the destination is clean. Meaning there are no files in the destination before the copy proceeds. The odd thing is that it does not throw the error with all the files and the file it had an issue with copying does get copied. I'd be a lot easier if it just didn't work.

The code used to do the copying does it such a manner that it creates the current directory structure of the source path at the destination location.

```
Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse -Include "$FilePattern" | Foreach-Object {
    $destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($SourcePath), $dstfolder)
    if (!(Test-Path $destDir)) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        sleep 1
    }
    Copy-Item $_ -Destination $destDir -Force -ErrorAction Ignore -Verbose | Write-Output
}
```

The actual error message is

```
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Copy File" on Target "Item: \\EPM111242ND\C$\
HypStaging\Objects\Applications\Vision\Plan1\Plan1.otl Destination:
C:\Users\epmadmin\Documents\Backups\Monday\Full\Objects\Applications\Vision\
Plan1\Plan1.otl". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\epmadmin\
Documents\Backups\Monday\Full\Objects\Applications\Visio n\Plan1\Plan1.otl'
because it is being used by another process.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item],   IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

It seems to be the destination file that its having an issue with which doesn't exist until it gets copied. Oddly the file is there when I check it. So I tried `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and `-Ignore` and both still produce the error message. I was think of maybe putting in a try catch statement but I'm not sure that'll suppress the message.

Comment: Doesn't work that way. If another process has a file locked you can't force-release that lock via `-ErrorAction` or `-Ignore`. Find the process that has the file opened and have it close the file. Suitable tools for identifying the process are [`handle`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle) or [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer).

Comment: See I initially thought that as well that there was some external process trying to look at the file, such as an AV scanner or something, but Ive excluded the target directory and I still get the message. The only way to get around it is to put in a try - catch statement around the copy-item then I don't  get the message "for obvious reasons"

Comment: @todd1215 out of curiosity, what is the current working directory when `Copy-Item` is run? You can find it with `Get-Location` or `$PWD`/

Comment: The directory location is the users Documents directory
C:\Users\epmadmin\Documents

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse -Include "$FilePattern" | % {
$destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($SourcePath), $dstfolder);
New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir -Force;
Copy-Item $_.fullname -Destination $destDir -Force
}
```

Comment: try to put () like this (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse -Include "$FilePattern" ) | .........